# What's the math behind gamma in GIMP?

Tags: gimp, rgb

Inside GIMP, Colors -> Levels
Click on the "Pick gray point" eyedropper (the middle eyedropper) and then click on a pixel in the image.
Then go change to the Red/Green/Blue channels and you'll see that the gamma (middle triangle) is set to a float for each RGB channel.

What's the math behind this? Like if I know the RGB values of a pixel how do I calculate to get these 3 gamma numbers myself.

I want to write a script-fu that sets levels based on black/white/gray points.
black and white points are straight forward, but this gray point deals with gamma and that's what's stopping me.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I think you may be best off looking for something like an RGB to HSL conversion if you're looking for true luminance values (see [this article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_color_space) for more on why it's not as straightforward to figure this out as one would think).

The other thing you could try would be going for a grayscale value; [this site](http://web.forret.com/tools/color.asp) (among others) allows you to convert from a hex value to a grayscale (among other) value. This second approach would be simpler but not necessarily as accurate (although I would think that this level of accuracy should be fine for most applications).